# Unable to get navigation to collapse automatcially in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html

How come the data-toggle doesn't work? The menu stay open when pressed! Looking to get it to close! Any ideas?

I'm not sure what else to do!! Thanks

```html
<!-- main nav -->
                <nav  id="navbar-collapse" class="collapse in navbar-collapse navbar-right" role="navigation">
                    <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a style="color: #9d9d9d;" href="#body">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a style="color: #9d9d9d;" href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a style="color: #9d9d9d;" href="#portfolio">Screenshots</a></li>
                        <li><a style="color: #9d9d9d;" href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
                        <li><a style="color: #9d9d9d;" href="#price">Features</a></li>
                        <li><a style="color: #9d9d9d;" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a style= "background-color: #2a7ead; color: #fff;"href="#yo">Buy Now</a></li>
      </ul>
                </nav>
    <!-- /main nav -->



<div class="navbar-header" >
                    <!-- responsive nav button -->
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
     <!-- /responsive nav button -->
     
     <!-- logo -->
     
      <img style="padding-left: 7px;" src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
     
     <!-- /logo -->
                </div>
```

Comment: Have you hooked up the Bootstrap JS and other files?

Comment: Yeah I have added those also!

Comment: Your html seems wrong. Copy-paste from bootstrap navbar boilerplate and check if That's working

Comment: Also, you're referencing to ".navbar-collapse" when you should use "#navbar-collapse"